# How to load the script section while using externally

Tags: angularjs

I have attached my sample with [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/H9xvN8f5AzNOwKvI6Vi4?p=preview)

```
<html>

   <head>
      <title>Angular JS Views</title>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-route.min.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>
      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>
      <div ng-app = "mainApp">
         <p><a href = "#addStudent">Add Student</a></p>
         <p><a href = "#viewStudents">View Students</a></p>
         <div ng-view></div>

         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "addStudent.htm">
            <h2> Add Student </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>

         <script type = "text/ng-template" id = "viewStudents.htm">
            <h2> View Students </h2>
            {{message}}
         </script>
      </div>

      <script>
         var mainApp = angular.module("mainApp", ['ngRoute']);


         mainApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.

            when('/addStudent', {
               templateUrl: 'addStudent.htm',
               controller: 'AddStudentController'
            }).

            when('/viewStudents', {
               templateUrl: 'viewStudents.htm',
               controller: 'ViewStudentsController'
            }).

            otherwise({
               redirectTo: '/addStudent'
            });
         }]);



      </script>

   </body>
</html>
```

when run my application, the external sample content loaded into my layout page. I have maintained seaparate js(template.js). While loading the script section in angular controller function was not hit also the values are not assigned. So the control rendered without any model values. I want to maintain more than 50 js files. Here I can't refer my js file in main page(index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a controller

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // home page
          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'Samples/template.html',
              controller: "DropDownCtrl",
          })
.otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

also include template.js file in header
Try this

Comment: Thanks for your response.I have corrected the controller name,then also loaded script is not calling.so please suggest me

Comment: did u include template.js file in index.html?

Comment: I have shared my link with simple plunkar applicationhttps://plnkr.co/edit/H9xvN8f5AzNOwKvI6Vi4?p=preview .Here i want to load the app.js script value.I dont want to refer this in index.html page.because i have l need to load more than 50 file.